# Python: Animation with PIL

Tags: python, animation, python-imaging-library

I want an animated picture. But I need a refresh-function because plt.show() always opens a new window. Does anybody have a hint? Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#array
aa = []
for x in range(44):
    aa.append([])
    for z in range(44):
        aa[x].append(3*sin(x/3.0)+2*cos(z/3.0))

b = aa
plt.imshow(b)
plt.show()

time = 0
dt = 0.1
while(time<3):
    b = sin(aa)
    time += dt
```

Comment: Why don't you use PyOpenGL or Pygame or some other library more suited for this task. Why PIL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PIL is geared towards image editing, not animating or displaying. Instead, look to a GUI toolkit or a multimedia library like [pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/) or [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answer about GUI toolkits, you could also save the images and build an animation after the fact.

If the image has few enough colours, PIL can save as a gif directly, as seen in [this blog post](https://blog.zhaytam.com/2018/08/21/creating-gifs-using-python-pillow/)

The relevant part:

```
frames = []
x, y = 0, 0
for i in range(10):
    new_frame = create_image_with_ball(400, 400, x, y, 40) # your imgs here
    frames.append(new_frame)
    x += 40 # you wont need these
    y += 40 # 

# Save into a GIF file that loops forever
frames[0].save('moving_ball.gif', format='GIF', append_images=frames[1:], save_all=True, duration=100, loop=0)
```

It will require modification for your purposes, but I have added a few comments to get you started.

Comment: Nice, pretty simple code, great for making a quick gif